# Convert .voc audio to wav in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, audio-converter, voc

**How to convert voc audio file to wav in node.js?**

I want to convert **voc audio** file to **wav or mp3**

But I didn't found any module for that.

Is there node module for this? I have searched for many hours and didn't found any helpful module to do this

Anyone please help

Comment: I would suggest to use ffmpeg

Comment: @felox how to doing this work?